# Trouble counting consecutive True values in pandas DataFrame

Tags: iteration, counting

[image]

I have a pandas DataFrame with columns 'material', 'day', 'stockout_indicator', and 'days_with_stockout'. I want to count the number of consecutive True values in the 'days_with_stockout' column for each group of rows with the same 'material' value that has a True value in the 'stockout_indicator' column. The output should be a new DataFrame with columns 'material', 'day', and 'stockout_duration'.

I have tried the following code, which works for the first group of rows with material=1 but not for subsequent groups with different material values:

```
for material, group in df.groupby('material'):
    for i, row in group.iterrows():
        if row['stockout_indicator']:
            count = 0
            for j, next_row in group.iloc[i:].iterrows():
                if next_row['days_with_stockout']:
                    count += 1
                else:
                    break
            results.append({'material': material, "day": row["day"],'stockout_duration': count})
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to achieve this result? Thanks in advance for your help.

btw I used the same input for both material types, so the results in column stockout_duration should be the same

[image]